# chat.exchange.com reputation bug

Tags: bug, chat

My chat.se user profile suddenly (last known normal ~7 hours ago) has 0 rep and so, of course, I can't talk in rpg.chat. I *can* still talk in a side chatroom I've had going.

I've been hit by what appears to be the same bug as [this guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161257/chat-stackexchange-reputation-bug), though I don't have multiple SE accounts to use with his fix.

I hope this only hit me!

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but I see `Has sent 3 invites` in red on your chat profile.  May be un-related...

Comment: @C.Ross Not sure what the red means, but 3 sounds like about the number of times I've invited someone to join a side room... but the most recent was a few weeks ago.

Comment: Anyway, I did a force refresh, try now.